# Função javascript incompatível jquery

Tags: jquery

Boa noite, galera

Tenha essa função javascript que carrega um banner dentro da div 'tesum', de acordo com a quantidade de linhas que o texto tem na div, tipo esses videos ADS publicidade em site de notícias. E outro banner aleatório no inicio do texto dentro da div 'bdads_post'. Porém, dar o seguinte erro quando utilizo a biblioteca jquery versão: http://belmontediario.com.br/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4

> Error: { "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
>   "filename": "stacksnippets.net/js";, "lineno": 15, "colno": 9 }

Com outra versão funciona certinho, porém, outras funcionalidades do meu site param de funcionar, como por exemplo, o botão load more no final da página inicial. www.belmontediario.com.br

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

Há algum tipo de incompatibilidade com meu código. Há outra maneira de fazer isso?

Obirgado pela atenção!

```js
$(function(){
    var banner = ["<img src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-iFFHRIIu-OQ/WeQhVKLaqZI/AAAAAAAAhRM/poHm7XyVpfoK2OE-bR-D21wQrMU1W5RzgCK4BGAYYCw/s1600/madferro.gif' alt=''>", "<img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-B84mYgVTaQQ/Utfu9prTnnI/AAAAAAAABtM/KdTqQzNS2Ec/s1600/ducarmin.gif' width='300' alt=''>"];
    var bannerPost = banner[Math.floor(Math.random() * banner.length)];

    $("#bdads_post").append(new Array(1 + 1).join(bannerPost));

});

$(function(){
var newImage = document.createElement('p');
var img = document.createElement('div');
img.innerHTML = '<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nCxwwr5kcUM/WM7z-Gqi2FI/AAAAAAAAd2g/e30MQRv-EoUDwDIsAZyzCa0VqoaSPd6PQCK4B/s1600/ph-turismo.gif"/>';
newImage.appendChild(img);
newImage.id = 'phtur';                    

var image = document.getElementById("tesum");    
image.insertBefore(newImage, image.childNodes[26]);
});

$(function(){
    $('#phtur').hide().delay(20000).slideToggle('slow');
    $('#phtur').click(function(){
        $("#phtur").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<div id='tesum'>

<div id='bdads_post'></div>
<p>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</p>


<p>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</p>


<p>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</p>


</div>
```

Comment: Qual o erro que dá?

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 15,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ não resolveu amigo.

Comment: Esse jQuery seu 1.12.4 parece ter problemas. Tente usar este: `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: A publicidade carregou normalmente, porém as outras funcionalidades como por exemplo o botao "load more" na pagina inicial parou de funcionar!

Comment: Está dando um erro: `Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null`... provavelmente se refere a esse `"tesum"` que não existe na página.

Comment: o "tesum" envolve o texto da postagem, ele existe sim. O modelo da minha postagem eh essa no editor html: <div id="tesum"> texto da noticia </div>. Se refere a biblioteca, quando atualizo a biblioteca meu codigo para e as outras coisas funcionam, e virce versa. Talvez eu tenha que atualizar o meu codigo de javascritp ou fazer ele diferente?

Comment: Se alguma função não funciona numa ou outra versão, é problema no evento, como vc falou. Seria interessante colocar na pergunta um exemplo do que funciona e do que não funciona nas respectivas versões do jQuery.

Comment: Editada a pergunta Sam!

Comment: Eu sugiro usar a versão mais recente do jQuery e procurar saber os outros problemas e tentar atualizá-los, mas pra isso é preciso saber o código. Ou são plugins?

Comment: São códigos! Esse código ai foi eu que fiz! Ja as outras funcionaldades sao do proprio tema (wordpress). Aqui esta o codigo em funcionamento: http://bn01.blogspot.com/2018/08/correios-de-pernambuco-podem-deflagrar-greve.html

Comment: Pode ser problema de precedência. Inspeciona a página e vê se teu código não foi carregado antes do jQuery. Ou se não está carregando dois jQuery na página, porque se isso acontecer os plugins do primeiro são sobrescritos.